# Displaying menu with panelgrid rendered

Tags: jsf

My Below code display menu based on if not database is empty, my problem is, it displays the second submenu but does not display the first one. i have got same validation on both

```
<h:panelGrid rendered="#{not empty dataBase}" width="100%">
        <h:form>  
            <p:menubar  style="height: 25px;background-color: #9999ff" >   
                <h:panelGrid rendered="#{not empty rights}" >
                    <p:submenu label="Master"  >  
                        <p:menuitem value="Client" url="test.xhtml" />   
                        <p:menuitem value="TaxMaster" url="test.xhtml" />  
                        <p:menuitem value="Quotation" url="test.xhtml" />  
                        <p:separator />  
                        <p:menuitem value="Area" url="test.xhtml" /> 
                    </p:submenu>  
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:submenu label="Back Office" icon="ui-icon-pencil">  
                    <p:submenu label="Book Issue" icon="ui-icon-contact">  
                        <p:menuitem value="Add" url="BookIssue_Add.xhtml" />  
                        <p:menuitem value="Edit" url="BookIssue_Edit.xhtml" /> 
                        <p:menuitem value="View" url="test.xhtml" />  
                    </p:submenu> 
       </p:submenu>  
            </p:menubar>  
        </h:form>  
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the rendered attribute on <h:form> element and remove the panelGrids? You are checking for the same attribute more than once.

Comment: i have different variables to be checked, i have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p:submenu/>` must be child of `<p:menubar/>` otherwise it wont be rendered

Comment: I do have <p:submenu under <p:menubar.

Comment: i mean you can not put `<h:panelGrid/>` "under" `<p:menubar/>`

Comment: Iam using two <h:panleGrid is this a problem?

Comment: dont add `panelgrid` to `menubar` as a child